# Which .NET JSON serializers can deal with NHibernate proxy objects?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, json, proxy, json.net

Which .NET JSON serializers can deal with NHibernate proxy objects? I tried using JSON.NET but it craps out when it hits a proxied object.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286721/json-net-and-nhibernate-lazy-loading-of-collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the best idea would be to deal with the proxy objects rather than actually find another way to serialise JSON. I have answered another question which involves eager loading these proxy objects in a legacy database which returns either the correct object or null [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435342/unexpected-proxy-objects-in-nhibernate-with-composite-ids/1030590#1030590). Please also note that with the proper database set up with foreign keys and definite links between objects/tables you shouldn't run into any proxy objects. Also note that this is not what is required for fluent NHibernate, I am assuming that you are using separate hbm mapping files.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I realize now that even though I can fix it in Json.NET, the fact that NHibernate proxy objects plays bad with reflection (specifically `GetType()`) is game-killing considering how many tools use reflection to work their magic. Also, I have a proper object graph; the proxy objects is due to lazy loading.